# How to create a Tree menu in natural doc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, documentation

I am using [naturaldocs](http://www.naturaldocs.org/) to generate API Documentation for my jQuery Widget.

I have 2 files

```
Folder1
    MyScript.js
    Forlder2
       myScript1.js
```

so i got a tree like this.

```
 MyScript
 myScript1
```

What i need is

```
MyScript
     myScript1
```

Is there is any way to achive this ?

In the both files i have a class notation. to create  tree.

```
/* Class: widget1;*/  and in  myScript1 /* Class: widget2;*/
```